# Perforce as integration and build server on w2k3x64?

Tags: msbuild, build-process, continuous-integration, perforce

We are in the process of migrating from TFS 2005 to Perforce and moving to more Simple TDD type process for our software.  Do you have any resources for setting Perforce up as an intergation and build server?

Looked at this question [Build management/ Continuous Integration best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419181/build-management-continous-integration-best-practices)

which also links to Martin Fowler on CI
http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html.

My question is specifically around Perforce with MSBuild on W2k3 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce isnt a integration or build server, it simple plays the role of a source repository for the CI process. So for your CI tool (if its MSBuild, Hudson, CruiseControl etc) its important to have an adapter (a perforce adapter) to get the most recent changes from the repository. The adapter should be configurable (URL, username, pass etc) and thats it with Perforce and CI.

Answer (score 1):

Just been looing more into this and just came to the same conclusion ...

links for those that may come across this

Cruise Control.Net - the integration server http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET

With Perforce http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Perforce+Source+Control+Block

And Finally with MSBuild
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+MSBuild

Answer (score 1):

I just got through evaluating TeamCity for our CI server (replacing custom scripts). I like it a lot and it works perfectly with Perforce.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/